# Is there a way of knowing who the owner of an Explorer window is, and their groups/account rights?

Tags: windows-xp, com, limited-user-account, regsvr32

Related question: [Opening Explorer shell with admin privileges on XP (with IE7 installed)](https://superuser.com/questions/327907/opening-explorer-shell-with-admin-privileges-on-xp-with-ie7-installed)

Once an Explorer window is opened, how can we tell the difference between one that is running as Admin and others that are running as the normal user?

Comment: If you know the answer why don't you post the answer in the existing question? I am confused by your question to be honest. Its fine you have a releated question but I don't understand how the linked question should be the contents of this question, the linked question, wants to know how to open a windows exploer window through a command prompt. **Which isn't what you want to know at least not based on the title of this question.**

Comment: The question was asked as a comment in the other question, so the answer should have been another comment in reply, but my rep isn't high enough to do that.  So it wouldn't be the answer to the question on how to open an explorer shell with admin priviledges

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [PrivBar by Aaron Margosis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2011/09/01/privbar-update.aspx).

There is another problem you might have (well I did!) where you cannot register PrivBar because the user you want it registered with does not have the requisite rights to run `Regsvr32`.

Part of the answer to this problem is `RegSvrEx` by Rama Krishna Vavilala which allows you to register a DLL to the current user, however when I tried that I got 'access denied'

I figured out that I could use RunAs to gain me the correct privileges, however then the problem would be that it would be launching the registration under the administrative account, and no longer the limited account I wanted therefore it would register it under the wrong account.

Reading the help information on RunAs I arrived at the solution:

```
C:\Work>RunAs /env /user:SOMEDOMAINORMACHINE\some.user "c:\utils2\RegSvrEx.exe /c Privbar.dll"
```